# Embedding an eclipse 4.2 plugin to a browser(mozilla firefox)

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I have made a plugin using eclipse 4.2 now i want it to be embedded with the browser(mozilla firefox).I tried many things but i couldnt find any way to to this..can anyone help me..

Comment: You should add what you have tried and what failed.